# Generalized unique nearest point problem for a compact, convex set in a strictly convex Banach space.

Tags: reference-request, convexity, oc.optimization-and-control, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a Real Banach space with strictly convex norm, it is known that for any non-empty compact, convex set $K$ and point $x_0\notin K$, there exists a unique point $z_0\in K$ minimizing the quantity $\|z-x_0\|$ in $z\in K$.

My question is whether it is known if the obvious generalization holds:

> Given two (or n) points $x_0,x_1\notin K$ so that the set $\{x_0,x_1\}$ is separated from $K$ by an affine hyperplane, then there exists a unique point $z_0\in K$ minimizing the quantity $\|z-x_0\|+\|z-x_1\|$ in $z\in K$.

My feeling is that this should have been investigated somewhere in the literature, but in my inexperience navigating that landscape I had thus far been unable to find it.

Comment: In two-dimensions the curves $\|z -x_0\| + \|z -x_1\| = d$ with $d > 0$ are "ellipses" in the normed plane and they were studied by Busemann among others (see his book *Geometry of geodesics*). In the higher dimensional case (or the general Banach space case) I have not seen the sets  $\|z -x_0\| + \|z -x_1\| \leq d$ studied. It is easy to see that these (sort of) "ellipsoids" are convex, so I guess your question reduces to something like: *if the unit ball of a Banach space is strictly convex, is the same true for all "ellipsoids"?* 

Comment: After talking to some colleagues over lunch, the implied strict convexity of 'ellipsoids' was exactly the conclusion we drew too. Thank you for the partial reference, I'll take a look. It's certainly a different direction than my attempts at finding something with the search term "convex optimization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES.

The function $\mathrm{dist}_x$ is strictly convex at any point $y$ and any direction different $x-y$.

It follows that $f=\sum \mathop{\rm dist}_{x_i}$ is strictly convex at any point if $x_i$ do not lie on one line;
in this case uniquness is obvious.

If there is a line, say $\ell$ containing all $x_i$, then $f$ is strictly convex in any half-space not intersecting $\ell$. Hence the result.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. Turned out not to be that hard after all. Thank you, Anton.